# Why an odd number of members in a replica set?

Tags: mongodb, replicaset

I have read this multiple times, but am trying to understand the message. All documents state to have an odd number of members in a replica set. The reason is because you want to have an odd number of votes to ensure proper election results (no ties). However, having an odd number of member in a replica set, in my opinion, is counter-intuitive as if the primary becomes unavailable, you're left with an even number of members to vote for the new primary. Based off of that, in reality, wouldn't it make more sense to have an even number of members in the replica set? That way if the primary becomes unavailable you'll have an odd number to determine the results with a guarantee of no tie?

For example, if you have 3 nodes and one goes down, you only have 2 left that can vote. As 2 is even, you could have a tie, which is what we're trying to avoid. 2 members to start isn't good as if one becomes unavailable, that leaves you with 1 node, which in that case means no primaries. Based off of my above argument, that would imply that 4 would be good. If one becomes unavailable, you'll have 3 nodes left to vote (an odd number of members). I know this is the opposite of what the documentation states, but to me, this makes sense. The only place where an odd number seems to make sense is if an election occurs with no nodes down.

Thoughts?

-Jim

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of replication is that in the event of a server goes down in a replica-set you can still access the data. This concept is called as **availability**.

In case the primary node goes down, one of the secondary nodes take its place, as primary; this process is called as **failover**.

The available nodes decide which node becomes a primary, thru the process of **election**.

A replica-set can have upto 50 members and upto 7 voting members - maximum.

***Why odd number of members?***

The *failover* mechanism means that a **majority** of the nodes must be available for a primary to be elected.

In a `4` (even) member replica-set the majority is `3`: `4/2 + 1`

In a `5` (odd) member replica-set the majority is `3`: `5/2 + 1`

In a 5 member replica-set there is a better chance of having 3 nodes available for the replica-set to be operational. In a 4 member replica-set at least 3 member must be up for the replica-set to be operational. So, with the 5 member replica-set (3 of 5) there is 
higher chance of being more operational than the 4 (3 of 4) member replica-set.

It is not just the number of members; there are various factors that affect an election.

- Members with higher priority has a chance of getting elected over
  others (priorities are numbers, and higher number is higher priority).
- Also, a secondary member with the latest replicated data has a
  preference over a member which do not have a latest copy. Factors
  like *write concern* affect which member has the latest copy of the
  data.
- There are *arbiter* members which can only vote but do not replicate
  data or run for an election. Hidden and delayed members cannot vote
  or become a primary.

That said, even with even number of available voting nodes election gets completed (and considering the above factors). An election may result in a tie, in such a case the voting process will start again, until a member is elected as primary. Note that an election is just an aspect (or process) of a system - a system that provides high availability and makes your system operational and with data replication.

Also see: [Factors and Conditions that Affect Elections](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-elections/index.html#factors-and-conditions-that-affect-elections).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I thought I read documentation mentioning an odd number of nodes to avoid a "tie" ("An odd number of voting members avoids potential cases where you could have a tied vote"). However, with 3 nodes and one node being down, you'll have 2 left, which is still majority. However with 2 nodes available, how do you avoid a tie? That's where I'm confused.

Comment: I think I found the answer I was looking for, but your explanation helps. The key is that "majority = total number of nodes" NOT "total number of nodes available at the time of an election". That part I was missing (which you explained above). Also, I found that the "tie" component only relates to when there are network splits, not when nodes are actually down. With those two, I believe my questions have been answered.